# ASP IsNull - either show nothing or show text and DB value

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to create an IsNull so if no data is found the DB field 'cut_off' nothing is shown and if there is date the page shows:

Cut off: DB Value of 'cut_off'

No matter what I do the the text "Cut off:" is always shown even if the field is empty, its as if the "Cut off:" needs to be inside the late DB call.

```
<%
If IsNull(rsDB.fields("cut_off")) Then
  response.write ""
Else 
  response.write "Cut off:" & (rsDB.Fields.Item("cut_off").Value)
End if
%>
```

Comment: Tend to use `Len(rsDB.fields("cut_off") & "")` myself. Simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NULL is not the same as an empty string.

`If (IsNull(rsDB.fields("cut_off"))) OR (Trim(rsDB.fields("cut_off"))="") Then`